# Remove Redundant parameters from asp:login control

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a website that uses Forms Authentication, recently our security team say that the following parameters in the POST of the FORM data are "Redundant":

```
ctl00$MainContent$LoginControl$UserName: user1
ctl00$MainContent$LoginControl$Password: 1234
ctl00$MainContent$LoginControl$Login: Log in
```

So this is where I'm getting confused, I think these are these controls within my asp:login control (I use a layout template to tidy the layout):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
<asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Login" ID="Login" Text="Log in" />
```

And therefore they can't be "Redundant" as they are the controls that take the users input and then the button makes the POST.

Does anyone know how these could be removed/hidden?  I've done a lot of reading up over the fact that the username & password are passed as plaintext, but use of SSL somewhat helps with this.

I know the obvious answer is ask the security team how they propose these be removed, and yes I've done that, but they only have experience of java based apps and this is a .net project.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are they supposed to be redundant? Those are just the names from Controls? And no if you remove them you will break Webforms.

Comment: From what I can get from this team, they say that the values are duplicates of the username and password fields (and therefore redundant), but I think those control and value pairs have to be there otherwise how else does the Form know what values are being posted for username and password.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It makes sure the data that is posted is bound to the correct control again. `ID="UserName"` becomes `name=ctl00$MainContent$LoginControl$UserName` because it is on a Page using a Master and those controls are in `LoginControl`. It is to make sure every control has a unique ID/name.

Comment: Some additional info, the test team say that if they enter correct credentials for the username and password, then intercept the POST data and change the value to incorrect username and password the login still works correctly, therefore they believe the credentials are being passed in some other way, hence making this value redundant.  So does that make sense?